# Indent inside section, subsection and subsubsection long titles as this: remove the space below the ([sub]sub)section number & make the text fit below

Tags: sectioning, indentation, subsection

How to shift the text towards the spaces (colored in redish) from the section, subsection and subsubsection titles? (Not my style, I should reproduce a Word-like document with that format, and I don't want to use Word). The MWE is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 
\begin{document}
    \section{La increíble y triste historia de la cándida Eréndira y de su abuela desalmada}
 (...)
    
    \subsection{Die unglaubliche und traurige Geschichte 
    von der einfältigen Eréndira und ihrer herzlosen Großmutter}
     (...)
    \subsubsection{La incredibile e triste storia della candida Eréndira e della sua nonna snaturata}
     (...)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is somewhat built into LaTeX and can be patched.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

%*************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{etoolbox} % needed for the patch    
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}
{\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}}
{\@svsec}
{}{}
\makeatother
%***************************************

\begin{document}
    \section{La increíble y triste historia de la cándida Eréndira y de su abuela desalmada}
    (...)
    
    \subsection{Die unglaubliche und traurige Geschichte 
        von der einfältigen Eréndira und ihrer herzlosen Großmutter}
    (...)
    \subsubsection{La incredibile e triste storia della candida Eréndira e della sua nonna snaturata}
    (...)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, it did work without the packages that I have to load. But when I add these, the effect of your patch is undone (e.g. `\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}`). Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @c.p. Please add another question adding your `titlesec` config.

Comment: Ok, [here I just did](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656493/titlesec-undoes-a-etoolbox-patch-how-to-make-them-compatible)

Comment: @c.p. you need to include the `titlesec` command you are using.