# Titlesec undoes an etoolbox patch. How to make them compatible?

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec, etoolbox

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654590/15542) says how to avoid indenting long section titles and obtaining something like in the picture  (not me who introduced this format, it's just the format I have to deal with now, and titles must look like below, unfortunately):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

%*************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{etoolbox} % needed for the patch    
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}
{\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}}
{\@svsec}
{}{}
\makeatother
%***************************************

% uncommenting next line that undoes the patch
% \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

%\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}


\begin{document}
    \section{La increíble y triste historia de la cándida Eréndira y de su abuela desalmada}
    (...)
    
    \subsection{Die unglaubliche und traurige Geschichte 
        von der einfältigen Eréndira und ihrer herzlosen Großmutter}
    (...)
    \subsubsection{La incredibile e triste storia della candida Eréndira e della sua nonna snaturata}
    (...)
\end{document}
```

However, if I load some packages the effect of the patch disappears. Some like `hyperref` can be just loaded in another order and
this fixes it. However, if I add `\usepackage{titlesec}` anywhere, the problem persists. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: well if you load titlesec that use its commands to format the section instead of your patch.

Comment: If you're using `titlesec`, you shouldn't need the patch; you can use its commands. Are you using commands from titlesec? If you're using `\titleformat` just make sure you use the `block` shape rather than the `hang` shape. E.g., `\usepackage{titlesec}\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\Large\hspace*{\parindent}}{\thesection}{1em}{}` and something similar for subsection. But it would be best if you posted the titlesec code you are currently using so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Sorry, now I added it – hopefully.

Comment: I think you need to switch to using the unstarred version of `\titleformat`. See [the documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) pages 3-4 example, as well as my example in my previous comment. (You can use it, and do a similar command in which you replace `\section` with `\subsection` and `\bfseries\Large` with the current options you're using with the starred version, and so on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `titlesec`  the patch is not needed.

[image: a]

It is needed to choose the `block` option for `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\hspace*{\parindent}}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape\hspace*{\parindent}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape\hspace*{\parindent}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{La increíble y triste historia de la cándida Eréndira y de su abuela desalmada}
    (...)
    
    \subsection{Die unglaubliche und traurige Geschichte 
        von der einfältigen Eréndira und ihrer herzlosen Großmutter}
    (...)
    \subsubsection{La incredibile e triste storia della candida Eréndira e della sua nonna snaturata}
    (...)
\end{document}
```

Comment: great, it works. Thanks